# Greediness in pattern

Tags: .net, regex

assume

```
string x = 100 4f fdsa fdsa few 2 dsa 12 3 +200 -100
pattern = (?<A>\d+).*?(?<B>(\+|-)?\d+(\.\d)?)?\s*(?<C>(\+|-)\d+(\.\d)?)
```

The intended behavior is for A=100 B=+200 and C=-100
The result of the regex is A=100 C=+200

I am not sure why this is happening as the ? quantifier on B should behave in a greedy manner, and .*? should be non-greedy.

Is there a better way to write this pattern, as it seems I run into this situation quite often where the match is performed on a string where there is a lot of useless data in the middle of the desired tokens?

So just to summarize all of these are possible strings

```
1 +1 A=1 B=null C=+1
1 6 +1 A=1 B=6 C=+1
1 7 6 +1 A=1 B=6 C=+1
1 asd asfd 1 7 +6.0 -7 A=1 B=+6.0 C=-7
```

Comment: Do you know that C will occur at the end of the regex, and that B will come right before it, or can there be garbage between and/or after them?

Comment: B will always precede C, separated by some whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like what you are looking for:

```
^(?<A>\d+).*?(?<B>[+-]?\d+(\.\d)?)?\D*(?<C>[+-]\d+(\.\d)?)$
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hC2kF9) with the two lines, and the groups in the bottom right pane.

**What was wrong with the original?**

The problem was that the your lazy `.*?` matched only as little as needed—which was up to some digits (with an optional sign) preceding some digits with a non-optional sign. This was satisfied as early as `3 +200`: `3` became Group B, and +200 became Group C.

To force Group C to be the last signed number, you could also have added an end of string anchor `$` at the end of your original regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bZ8xW8)):

```
(?<A>\d+).*?(?<B>(\+|-)?\d+(\.\d)?)?\s*(?<C>(\+|-)\d+(\.\d)?)$
```

Comment: B is intended to be optional because I will come across strings that are of the format

string x2 = 100 4 2 12 3 -100

in which case B is not present and should return a null match

Comment: @YevgenyYurgenson Okay, thanks for explaining. Gave you a revised regex that lets Group B be optional, see the new demo. :)

Comment: YevgenyYurgenson ...And it looks like @dasblinkenlight came up with the same idea at the same time.

Comment: this is a very slick approach but the functionality changes somewhat. I just realized that I intended for [+-] in B to be optional and therefor this pattern wouldnt work.

Comment: @YevgenyYurgenson If the +- is optional, how do you know to match 200 (without a `+`) in group B, and not `12`?

Comment: because it should immediately precede group C

Comment: Is [this](http://regex101.com/r/dU4zR1) what you are talking about? If so, I will put it in the answer.

Comment: Yes this works. Could you possibly explain to me why my original pattern does not function as intended? why is the ? quantifier not performing in a greedy manner?

Comment: The `.*?` is **lazy**, which means it wants the shortest match. The shortest match is when Group B is `3`. Yes the `?` after Group B is greedy. This means that when it has the choice of matching Group B 0 times or one times, it will prefer to match one time. And this is what it does: Group B is `3`.

Comment: If anything is still unclear you also probably want to read [The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)

Comment: ive accepted your answer what are you talking about

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting)